# Space vs null character

Tags: c++, null, space

In C++, when we need to print a single space, we may do the following:

```
cout << ' ';
```

Or we can even use a converted ASCII code for space:

```
cout << static_cast<char>(32); //ASCII code 32 maps to a single space
```

I realized that, printing a null character will also cause a single space to be printed.

```
cout << static_cast<char>(0); //ASCII code 0 maps to a null character
```

**So my question is:** Is it universal to all C++ compilers that when I print `static_cast<char>(0)`, it will always appear as a single space in the display?

If it is universal, does it applies to text files when I use *file output stream*?

Comment: In which platform are you getting a space when you print null?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Running on windows 7

Answer (score 9):

No, it will be a zero(0) character in every compiler. Seems that the font you use renders zero characters as a space. For example, in the old times, DOS had a different image (an almost filled rectangle) for zero characters.

Anyway, you really should not output zero characters instead of spaces!

As for the text file part: open the outputted file using a hex editor to see the actual bits written. You will see the difference there!

Answer (score 5):

On my computer, this code

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello" << static_cast<char>(0) << "world\n";
}
```

outputs this:

```
Helloworld
```

So no, it clearly doesn’t work.